# Differentiable product of tensor in Tensorflow

Tags: swift, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

I am trying to create cosine similarity layer in Swift for Tensorflow, to create word embeddings.

I have tried to implement it via tensor functions according to the definition at wikipedia.

```swift
@differentiable
func cosineSimilarity(_ input: Tensor<Float>) -> Tensor<Float> {
        // https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosine_similarity

        let numerator = input.product(squeezingAxes: 1).sum(squeezingAxes: 1)
        let denominator = sqrt(input.squared().sum(squeezingAxes: 1)).product(squeezingAxes: 1)

        return numerator / denominator
}
```

But it results in the compile error:

```
error: expression is not differentiable
let denominator = sqrt(input.squared().sum(squeezingAxes: 1)).product(squeezingAxes: 1)
```

With highlihted `product` function. Because product is just sum of multiplication I expected it to work. If I try to create products by hand, in for loops, it works, but it is very slow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So differentation of product was just not implemented in Swift for Tensorflow. Pull request with implementation is currently open at https://github.com/tensorflow/swift-apis/pull/550.